# JavaScript Fetch api with credentials and Client_ID (Cornerstone API)

Tags: javascript, typescript, cornerstone

I have a customer that provided these details for a API I need to use:

```
User_ID: "my_User_ID"
Client Secret: "my_client_secret"
Client_ID: "my_Client_ID",
Registered Oauth application name: Internal Careersite
Access Token Validity Period: 3600
Base adress: https://mySite-pilot.csod.com

Oauth scopes: Cornerstone API, jobrequisition:read  - allows GET requests to following endpoints:            
/services/api/Recruiting/JobRequisitionDetails
```

I read this guide for the API:
https://apiexplorer.csod.com/apiconnectorweb/apiexplorer#/info

I then do a fetch to test my API (proxyUrl is a proxy for no-cors):

```
fetch(
        proxyUrl +
          "https://mySite-pilot.csod.com/services/api/Recruiting/JobRequisitionDetails",
        {
          headers: {
            "clientId": "my_Client_ID",
            "userId": "my_User_ID",
            "clientSecret":"my_Client_Secret",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "grantType": "client_credentials",
            "scope": "jobrequisition:read",
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            Accept: "application/json",
            method: "GET",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) =>console.log(response))
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Above fetch will return a 401 "authorization denied". I do believe that the way I authorize with my credentials is wrong, rather than the information I got. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: do u send the access token?

Comment: if not you should send it in headers as: 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + access_token, smth like this

Comment: also don't send this data in headers, read the docs again, there is said you should send them in json format (clientId, clientSecret, grantType, scope) in body, then to get the access token, and to use it in the following requests